# MVC route for child parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I wrote a route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "LoadDefaultPage",
            url: "Load",
            defaults: new { controller = "Load", action = "Index" }
        );
```

and it works fine for http://localhost/Load. But I need to do the same action for http://localhost/Load/bla , http://localhost/Load/bla/bla/ , http://localhost/Load/bla/bla/bla etc. How to describe it?

Comment: you gotta love the people downvoting without a comment.....

Comment: [Dealing With Varying Number Of Route Segments In ASP.NET MVC](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/f41d04f7-14f6-4d28-a2ce-fbbeb985fffc.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using this code (thanks for Stephen Muecke):

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "LoadDefaultPage",
            url: "Load/{*tmp}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Load", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Controllers with different Routprefixes. e.g.

```
[RoutePrefix("Load")]
public class LoadController : ApiController
{

}

[RoutePrefix("Load/bla")]
public class LoadBlaController : ApiController
{

}
```

Or if you want http://localhost/Load/bla to be a Method use:

```
[RoutePrefix("Load")]
public class LoadController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGET, Route("bla")]
    public string Bla()
    {
        return "bla";
    }
}
```